# Regex to match commas that are not in an array (enclosed in square brackets)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an object and want to represent it as string with some addtional formatting.

**Here is my code:**

```js
// stringify object and remove double quotations
let outPut = JSON.stringify(myObject).replace(/"/g, '')

// replace commas with new line character while comma is not part of an array
outPut = outPut.replace(/,/g, '\n') // this line replaces all commas
```

Since my object contains arrays and I want to preserve commas within the brackets `[...]`, I need to tell the `replace` function to match only when the comma is not within brackets.

How can I achieve this?

**Example input string:**

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to replace all commas except the ones inside `["GML", "XML"]`.

Comment: Have you tried [the third parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Parameters) of `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: @undefined: AFAIK `Space` is used to indent with spaces, but I need some sort of `regex` I guess.

Comment: Just like regex should not be used to match HTML it should not be used to match JSON. JSON like HTML is a tree like data structure and regex is not suitable for matching it.

Comment: Yes, RegEx is a fragile option here. What is the point of doing this after all?

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly: Thanks for edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following regex to match commas not in arrays:

```
(,)(?![^[]*\])
```

(Explanation on **[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2rX9UG/3)**.)

This says to match any comma which, if it is followed by a close bracket, has an opening bracket before that close bracket.

---

Example in JS:

```
outPut = outPut.replace(/(,)(?![^[]*\])/g, '\n');
```

gives:

```
"{glossary:{title:example glossary
GlossDiv:{title:S
GlossList:{GlossEntry:{ID:SGML
SortAs:SGML
GlossTerm:Standard Generalized Markup Language
Acronym:SGML
Abbrev:ISO 8879:1986
GlossDef:{para:A meta-markup language
 used to create markup languages such as DocBook.
GlossSeeAlso:[GML,XML]}
GlossSee:markup}}}}}"
```