# Regex to match commas that are not enclosed in curly brackets

Tags: regex

Related to this question [Regex to match commas that are not in an array (enclosed in square brackets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52792378/regex-to-match-commas-that-are-not-in-an-array-enclosed-in-square-brackets) I found I want to match commas outside of curly brackets.

The solution to that question was `,(?![^[]*\])`. I am trying a similar regex, `,(?![^{]*\})`, for my problem.

What I found with this regex I am trying is that it doesn't match the third comma in this example, `{"A": "B", "C":{"D":"E"}, "F": {"G"}, "H":"I"}`. For some reason it does not match the last comma after the closing curly bracket following the letter G.

The example online: https://regex101.com/r/4YXKqJ/1

Comment: Perhaps you can turn it around `,(?=[^{]*(?:{|$))` https://regex101.com/r/TLkqaM/1 but the comma's are enclosed by the outer curly's right?

Comment: `"F": {"G"},` has a stinky flavor of invalid JSON. Speaking of JSON...

Answer (score 1):

Is this for PCRE like in your demo? If so, consider [skipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) the `{`...`}` parts:

```
{[^}{]*}(*SKIP)(*F)|,
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YMJaKh/1)

The left side of the [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) is used to skip stuff, the right side to match.